# Slow PHP Project on Local, Using CI and Xamp

Tags: performance, codeigniter, optimization, xampp

I have one project on my local. Its in CodeIgniter. Problem is it is taking too much to load. Other projects on same machine and same server runs way much faster. I have same file (CI's default welcome file) on the both project. I have cleared all the autoload's, but still no success.

I copied this project to another system and checked and it takes same amount of time their as well.

Please help me. Below is the time that i see.

Loading Time: Base Classes      :- 8.0453
Controller Execution Time ( Welcome / Index )   :- 14.2312
Total Execution Time    :- 22.2766

Thanks,

Comment: Check the `.htaccess` file to see if there are too many rules.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, nothing at all. Only 6 lines for avoiding the "index.php" in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Check your queries in the model and loops on the welcome controller function index() and also in view.
maybe they are taking to much time to execute

Comment: its the original welcome controller page. Nothing in it except the view page which welcomes you first time when you run the CI.

Comment: check this answer http://serverfault.com/questions/66347/why-is-the-response-on-localhost-so-slow

Comment: sorry , but i already tried that. My xamp is not slow. My other projects are running very fast, but only this project.